# Retrieve Binary Image from DB via JSON and ashx then convert to image in html?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

Ive been tasked to use this method, quite frankly id could do this server side in 2 sec's but need it all doing in javascript.

So here goes, i need to retrieve a binary image from the DB thats returned in a object called S_TeamMember. One of the properties is MainImg byte[]

im using JSON to call a ashx Handler to call the DB and retrieve the data.

```
    $(function () {
    var queryparam = getUrlVars()["CatLink"];

    $.ajax({
        url: "TeamGroups.ashx",
        data: { CatLink:  queryparam },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnTeamGroupsCompleted,
        error: OnPageFailM
    });
});
```

the JSON call above

```
     function OnTeamGroupsCompleted(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

        var name = result[i].Name;
        var recno = result[i].Recno;
        var mainimg = result[1].MainImg;
        var memholder = "<div class='PersonImageHolder'>" +
            "<div class='PersonImage'>" +
                "<img src='"+ mainimg +"'/>" + <------ PROBLEM IS HERE
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='PersonNameHolder inline-block'>" +
        "<div class='ImgHolderL inline-block'>" +
            "<img src='images/web/WhiteRibbonL.png' />" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='NameHolder inline-block'>" +
            "<p><a href='MemberDetail.aspx?TeammMemberLink="+ recno +"'>"+ name +"</a></p>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='ImgHolderR inline-block'>" +
            "<img src='images/web/WhiteRibbonR.png' />" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>";

        $('.Content').append(memholder);

    }
}
```

then above how im iterating through the JSON result to draw a div on the page with images.
The trouble im having is or course parsing the 'MainImg' binary data into a html image tag.

Any ideas how i go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's value of result[i].MainImg in OnTeamGroupsCompleted? JSON format natively doesn't support binary data. 
You can:

1. write a new ashx
2. pass name or id in url
3. set ashx to img src
4. in ashx output image binary data

in javascript:

```
"<img src='image.ashx?name"+ result[i].Name +"'/>" + <------ PROBLEM IS HERE
```

in image.ashx:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string name = context.Request.QueryString["name"];
    //query database by name to get image binary data
    Byte[] bytes = ...;
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
}
```

Comment: absolutely fantastic!! Just what i needed, cheers, you've saved me re writing all of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is doable using javascript! But instead you can store the url of the  image in DB and return it to the browser.